# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular, promise, ionic2

I'm currently updating my ionic v1 app to ionic v2 but I'm in trouble with promise based service.

## ionic v1

### home.controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp.home', ['myApp.services.camera',])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, CameraService) {
  $scope.getPicture = function() {
    var onSuccess = function(result) {
      // Some code
    };

    var onError = function(err) {
      // Some code
    };

    CameraService.getPicture().then(onSuccess, onError);
  };
});
```

### camera.service.js

```
angular.module('myApp.services.camera', [])

.service('CameraService', function($q, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaCamera) {
  return {
    getPicture : function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      var onSuccess = function(result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
      };

      var onError = function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      };

      // my options here

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(onSuccess, onError);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

This is working well.

Now with the v2.

## ionic v2

### take-photos.ts

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CameraService} from '../../services/camera.service';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/take-photos/take-photos.html',
  providers: [CameraService]
})
export class TakePhotosPage {

  constructor(private cameraService: CameraService) {}

  getPicture () {
    this.cameraService.getPicture().then((result) => {
      console.log(result); // Did not called
      // Some code
    }, (err) => {
      // Some code
    });
  }
}
```

### camera.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class CameraService {
  constructor (private platform: Platform) {}

  getPicture () : any {
    // my options here

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      navigator.camera.getPicture((result) => {
        console.log(result); // Called
        return Promise.resolve(result);
      }, (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }, options);
    });
  }
}
```

With the v1, the promise is correctly returned.
With the v2 I got an error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in take-photos.ts for this line `this.cameraService.getPicture().then`

I do not understand why as I followed the [angular tutorial about services and promises](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

If anyone have an idea it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed to return promise from `getPicture` function, so that you can have `.then` function over it.

**Code**

```
getPicture () : any {
    // my options here

    return this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      navigator.camera.getPicture((result) => {
        console.log(result); // Called
        return Promise.resolve(result);
      }, (err) => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }, options);
    });
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Well, in fact this is not working. I mean, I don't have the error anymore but now, the console.log() in take-photos.ts is called before the one in camera.service.ts. It's not waiting the promise. Maybe this is another question ? I'll dig into this.

Comment: I was wrong on the way to do this. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35817127/2404908) helped me. I now have the same behaviour as my ionic v1 service.